# Adding right colspan for the table populated from xml using SimpleXMLElement()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am creating a table from an XML *(that is from an external source, I am not able to make any changes in the input xml)* using `SimpleXMLElement()` function. Its create the table nicely but, if you close look into the input `$data` xml in some rows has skipping some numbers *(eg:  `_x0034_` in row one)*, I need to add the proper `colspan` to the places whenever I skipping the col, that can be one or two etc.

*eg: if I skip col4 need to add `colspan="2"` in col3*

```
<?php $data= "<tableDOC>
<Table8>
    <_x0031_>9</_x0031_>
    <_x0032_>101970</_x0032_>
    <_x0033_>100000</_x0033_>
    <_x0035_>36000</_x0035_>
    <_x0036_>0</_x0036_>
    <_x0037_>0</_x0037_>
    <_x0038_>0</_x0038_>
  </Table8>
  <Table8>
    <_x0031_>10</_x0031_>
    <_x0033_>100000</_x0033_>
    <_x0034_>22500</_x0034_>
    <_x0035_>40000</_x0035_>
    <_x0036_>100000</_x0036_>
    <_x0037_>22500</_x0037_>
    <_x0038_>40000</_x0038_>
  </Table8>
 <Table8>
    <_x0031_>10</_x0031_>
    <_x0032_>113300</_x0032_>
    <_x0033_>100000</_x0033_>
    <_x0034_>22500</_x0034_>
    <_x0035_>40000</_x0035_>
    <_x0038_>40000</_x0038_>
  </Table8>
</tableDOC>";

$books = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

echo <<<EOF
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
EOF;
foreach($books as $Table8) 
{

echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0031_."</td>"; 
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0032_."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0033_."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0034_."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0035_."</td>"; 
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0036_."</td>"; 
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0037_."</td>"; 
       echo "<td>".$Table8->_x0038_."</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
 }
echo '</table>'; ?>
```

**A Working sample here http://codepad.org/bsb8x19m**

the above example resulting a table like this http://jsfiddle.net/MwyZT/

but my expected result need to be like this (width proper colspan) http://jsfiddle.net/MUX54/

Comment: please show some of your efforts to solve that problem.

Comment: @michi this is what Im trying http://codepad.org/wAwL1YIy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to keep track of the line numbers:
*(edited code to make correct table if last colnumber < 38 is commented with `// edit`)*

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$output = "<table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\">";

foreach ($xml->Table8 as $row) {
    $lastcolnumber = 30; // edit
    $output .= "<tr>";
        $max = $row->children()->count(); // edit
        $count = 1; // edit

    foreach ($row->children() as $col => $value) {
        $colnumber = intval(filter_var($col, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
        $step = $colnumber - $lastcolnumber;
        if ($count == $max && $colnumber < 38) $step = 38 - $lastcolnumber; // edit
        $lastcolnumber = $colnumber;
        $count++; // edit   

        if ($step > 1) $colspan = " colspan=\"$step\""; 
        else $colspan = "";
        $output .= "<td$colspan>$value</td>";
    } // $value

    $output .= "</tr>";
} // $row

$output .= "</table>"; // now, $output contains the HTML code for the table
```

**Comments:**
 1. the 1st `foreach` loop is grabbing one `<Table8>` node and its children, this is one table row
 2. the 2nd `foreach` loop is grabbing its children, these are the table cells
 3. the cells have their column number coded in their name, `<_x0031_>` is column 31, use `filter_var()` to extract digits only, `intval()` to convert to `int`.
 4. calculate the step from one to the next column number: if it is greater than 1, add a `colspan` attribute to the `<td>` tag in `$output`.
 5. the edited code is tracking the number of cells in the inner `foreach` loop: if the last cell is processed and `$colnumber < 38` then `$step` is recalculated.

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HRz8p6

Comment: that will break if last col is not `<_x0038_>`

http://codepad.viper-7.com/KB68xf

Comment: @Chanduvk How do you think you can handle this? BTW, are colums always min 31 and max 38?

Comment: that's great, what if I only have `<_x0031_>`

Comment: @Chanduvkm set `$lastcolnumber = 30` (see my edit) and try it :-)